How to identify a Stack Exchange website before page load inside content script?
I'm writing a personal Chrome extension that modifies various things (i.e. styles) on various websites. That includes Stack Exchange. My extension is enabled on all websites so I have to differentiate between them based on window.location.
Currently I'm doing it like this:
// code executed before load
const host = window.location.hostname;
function hostIncludesAny(...strList) {
    for (const str of strList) {
        if (host.includes(str)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
// ...
// more ifs here
// ...
if (hostIncludesAny("stackoverflow.com", "stackexchange.com", "serverfault.com", "superuser.com", "askubuntu.com")) {
    // apply styles for Stack Exchange network
}

I do it like this because stackexchange.com is a suffix for many subdomains and it gets them all. But some communities have their own domain like superuser.com or askubuntu.com and I have to include them manually.
Is there some information source (maybe response headers?) that connects all those websites?
I have already set up a background script, so I can message it to do something using available Chrome APIs, if that can help.

Why is your extension enabled on all websites, rather than matching the relevant sites in manifest.json?

You might be able to glean the relation from WHOIS, but I don't think you can access that from JS. There are only a few of these non-stackexchange.com domains, it's probably easier to just list them explicitly.

"Why is your extension enabled on all websites" - Because its easier to do the matching logic in JS where I have access to fragmented URL (window.location) as well as do RegEx. I also don't like to create a new JS file for each new website that I would like to edit when I can just create a new if in an existing script.

What's wrong with window.location.hostname?

"You might be able to glean the relation from WHOIS" - I've read a bit... So you suggest making an API call to some service before every page load? Seems very wasteful but would technically work as all the already listed websites have the same "org": "stack exchange, inc." parameter in the response JSON.

"What's wrong with window.location.hostname" - Generally nothing, but the problem is that I would need to know all custom hostnames of Stack Exchange network. In particular those that don't contain stackexchange.com.

@Chrysaloid Yes, that's the idea, but I'm not actually recommending it. I'd just make a hard-coded list. I think there are less than 10 of these special domains.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81379/can-we-have-a-list-of-all-the-stack-exchange-domains-somewhere, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299365/list-of-stack-exchange-subdomains, https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8061/why-do-certain-stack-exchange-sites-have-top-level-domains

@Bergi, Thank you for these links.

I don't think there's anything simple you can do to automatically detect these domains. There are only a handful of domains, it's easier to just list them explicitly.
Here's the list from a Tampermonkey script I've installed.
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @exclude     *://api.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://blog.*.com/*
// @exclude     *://chat.*.com/*
// @exclude     *://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://elections.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://openid.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://stackexchange.com/*


Yeah, I think now you're probably right. With your answer and links from Bergi's comment I should be able to construct full list. Thanks.
